# Omit inner category URLs from url path

Tags: magento2, category, url, navigation

I have a magento 2.1.10 setup running..

Recently made a bulk of change in the categories navigations.

The currently structure is somewhat like below

```
All > Pillows > Shop All Pillows > Printed Pillows
```

the currently URL for printed pillows is

```
/pillows/shop-all-pillows/printed-pillows
```

How can i omit the `shop-all-pillows`, so that the url reads the below instead

```
/pillows/printed-pillows
```

Is it possible to achieve this without having to the change the navigation structure